Installing apps to a Dev Box with winget
According to this Microsoft blog post you can now configure a Dev Box with a yaml configuration file, but since it is still in Preview we cannot get any support from Microsoft. I have been trying to install apps with a yaml configuration file but winget has been a real pain. For reference, here is some documentation on it. I was able to get choco to work great, but it is a business requirement that we use winget. For the following code snippet
  - name: winget
    parameters: 
      package: Microsoft.DotNet.Framework.DeveloperPack_4
      runAsUser: true

this succeeds but will attempt to install everything as the user upon the first logon, and since the user will not have admin rights on the box I cannot install it. Unfortunately all of the documentation I can find always has runAsUser so I am unsure how to get it turn without it. I got rid of the runAsUser, and it failed with the following error:
[2024-06-24T18:30:31.058805+00:00] Get-Process : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Id' because it is null.
[2024-06-24T18:30:31.058843+00:00] At C:\Windows\SystemTemp\47e080f3-6d0c-4c51-8db5-d8bed229318a\18dbfeba-61b3-4261-b931-617e7932660c\main.ps1:354 char:36
[2024-06-24T18:30:31.058845+00:00] +         $process = Get-Process -Id $processCreation.ProcessId

This is because line 353 of this documentation for the yaml task returns a null ProcessId. I have had no luck at all getting the winget task to work, so I tried using the Powershell task instead. This is what I am running:
  - name: powershell
    parameters: 
      command: .\winget.exe install -e --id 'Microsoft.VisualStudioCode' --accept-source-agreements
      workingDirectory: C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.DesktopAppInstaller_1.22.11261.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe

I am able now able to successfully run winget, but I still cannot install anything because it fails due to insufficient privileges:
[2024-06-26T15:42:33.292672+00:00] Successfully verified installer hash
[2024-06-26T15:42:33.479485+00:00] Starting package install...
[2024-06-26T15:42:33.587634+00:00]
[2024-06-26T15:42:33.853247+00:00]    -
[2024-06-26T15:42:34.118878+00:00]    \
[2024-06-26T15:42:34.384493+00:00]    |
[2024-06-26T15:42:34.650639+00:00]    /
[2024-06-26T15:42:34.650649+00:00]                                                                                                                        
[2024-06-26T15:42:34.650655+00:00] Installer failed with exit code: 2147500037
[2024-06-26T15:42:34.681581+00:00] Command exited with code 1
[2024-06-26T15:42:34.689600+00:00]
[2024-06-26T15:42:34.689684+00:00]

Sometimes I get a different "file not found" error:
[2024-06-26T16:24:10.696162+00:00] Installer failed with exit code: 2
[2024-06-26T16:24:10.726756+00:00] Command exited with code 1

The yaml file should be being run as System while the Dev Box is being created. I am not logging into a created Dev Box and then running the yaml. To get the above to work I need elevated privileges, but according to the documentation I cannot configure the Powershell version, let alone running it as admin. It only allows for the code and the directory. However this is the closest I have been to getting a successful installation.
I am trying to install 10 packages, but only 3 succeeded.
Has anybody had any luck installing apps to a Dev Box upon its creation? I have tried everything I can think of to get it to work.
